# Instance variable gets modified automatically

Tags: python, algorithm, class, object, game-theory

I made a new class that represents one position in the game of [Tic Tac Toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe). Basically what I'm trying to do is make a tree of all possibilities of game positions where each node is a `Position` object and find the best move for the player using minimax algorithm. The minimax algorithm isn't shown below as the Position class is not working as required.

The `Position` class has a `generate_children` method that makes a list of `Position` objects that can be reached from the current position. Executing the program we get the output that after each iteration the `pos_matrix` of the current `Position` object is changing which is undesirable. I have not touched the `pos_matrix` of the current Position object in the loop and `play_move` makes a copy of the matrix to avoid messing it up. Still the `pos_matrix` is changing each iteration.

**What is happening? How do I debug it?**

Tried: moved `play_move` out of class, didn't work.

**Note**: A `0` in the pos_matrix represents empty square while `1` represent "X" and `-1` represents "O".
Also `kiska_chance` means "whose chance". :P

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, parent_):
        self.parent = parent_
        self.children = []
        self.best_move = []
        self.pos_matrix = []
        self.last_move = []

    def set_pos_matrix(self, pos_matrix_):
        self.pos_matrix = list(pos_matrix_)
        # Avoiding copying problems by creating copy of list

    def set_last_move(self, last_move_):
        self.last_move = list(last_move_)
        # Avoiding copying problems by creating copy of list

    def play_move(self, move, kiska_chance):
        m2 = list(self.pos_matrix)
        x, y = move
        m2[x][y] = kiska_chance

        return m2

    def generate_children(self, kiska_chance):
        children_ = []
        for move in self.get_possible_moves():
            # Passing a Position object into the possible moves with
            # parent as self.
            pos_temp = Position(self)
            pos_temp.set_pos_matrix(self.play_move(move, kiska_chance))
            pos_temp.set_last_move(move)

            print self.pos_matrix

            children_.append(pos_temp)
        self.children = children_

        return children_

    def get_possible_moves(self):
        dem_moves = []
        for i in xrange(3):
            for j in xrange(3):
                if self.pos_matrix[i][j]==0:
                    dem_moves.append([i, j])
        return dem_moves


pos = Position(None)
pos.set_pos_matrix([[0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]])
pos.generate_children(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested lists in `self.pos_matrix`. You were only copying the outer list. Because of that all of the lists in the list are still shared by both lists. You need to copy the lists in the list. See corrected code:

```
def play_move(self, move, kiska_chance):
    m2 = list(list(l) for l in self.pos_matrix)
    x, y = move
    m2[x][y] = kiska_chance

    return m2
```

Also in:

```
def set_pos_matrix(self, pos_matrix_):
    self.pos_matrix = list(list(l) for l in pos_matrix_)
    # Avoiding copying problems by creating copy of list and lists in list
```

Comment: can you explain why copying the outer list only is not working? it basically makes a new list right?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you've to use `deepcopy` for this, since `lists` are `mutable` objects, they'll be passed by reference to other objects.

Lets see what happens for a list having both `mutable` and `immutable` objects.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2]
>>> l2 = [3, 4]
>>> t1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> l = [l1, l2, t1, 5]
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
```

Here `list l` is having `l1 and l2` and then `tuple t1` and then a number `5`, So `list` is a `mutable` object and number and `tuples` are not.

If you simply doa  `list(l)` that becomes a `shallow copy`, shallow copy means just copying the very outer object, but still your inner objects refer to the same objects.

You better use `copy` module for this.

```
import copy
>>> l_copy = copy.copy(l)
```

Now we did a `shallow copy` here..lets see what happens.

```
>>> l_copy
[[1, 2], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
```

We've gt the same list as `l` and lets try appending one value to the `inner list`.

```
>>> l_copy[0]
[1, 2]
>>> l_copy[0].append(0)
>>> l_copy
[[1, 2, 0], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
```

Now l[0] --> [1, 2] got added one more value [1,2, 0]..and if you try checking `l` and `l1` you can see the same value there as well.

```
>>> l
[[1, 2, 0], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
>>> l1
[1, 2, 0]
```

You didn't modify `l and l1`, but still they got added new value `0` this what happens if your `mutable` objects.

Lets try `deepcopy` here.. Note: You've to define `l1, l2 and l` again don't use the old ones..

```
>>> l_copy = copy.deepcopy(l)
>>> l_copy
[[1, 2], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
```

Now append value to `l_copy[0]` this means to `l1`..

```
>>> l_copy[0].append(0)
>>> l_copy
[[1, 2, 0], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
```

And try checking with `l1 and l`..

```
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3, 4], (1, 2, 3), 5]
>>> l1
[1, 2]
```

If you see now that value is `not` reflecting over `l1 and l`.

So you've to be careful with `mutable` objects. and may be refer below doc for more info about `copy` and `deepcopy`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html